# Is it possible to use MTA-STS in Postfix without overriding DANE?

Tags: security, postfix, dane, mta-sts

The *SMTP MTA Strict Transport Security* [RFC 8461, 2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8461#section-2) clearly states that:

> However, MTA-STS is designed not to interfere with DANE deployments
> when the two overlap; in particular, senders who implement MTA-STS
> validation MUST NOT allow MTA-STS Policy validation to override a
> failing DANE validation.

Currently it seems that with the following Postfix configuration the MTA-STA overrides DANE ([RFC 6698](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6698)) validation when the recipient has implemented both, as discussed in the mta-sts-daemon's [issue #67](https://github.com/Snawoot/postfix-mta-sts-resolver/issues/67), and DANE is only used if the domain is explicitly listed in the first matching [smtp_tls_policy_maps](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_policy_maps) (`/etc/postfix/tls_policy`) as `dane-only`.

```
# Opportunistic DANE TLS
smtp_tls_security_level = dane
smtp_dns_support_level = dnssec

# MTA-STS
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_tls_policy_maps =
    hash:/etc/postfix/tls_policy,
    socketmap:inet:127.0.0.1:8461:postfix
```

Has anyone found a way to configure Postfix in a RFC 8461 compliant way, i.e., that MTA-STS policy validation through mta-sts-daemon cannot change the policy maps for domains that have both technologies enabled? Would this require an additional external "dane-daemon" providing `dane-only` [smtp_tls_policy_maps](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_policy_maps) for domains that have DANE enabled?

Comment: I wonder if the simplest workaround possible - prepending another socketmap that returns dane-only or NOTFOUND depending on a single dns query - would miss any edge cases..

Comment: Experts in these technologies usually answer such questions on the Postfix mailing list at postfix-users@postfix.org.

Comment: @anx: Good suggestion. Although it is not a single DNS query, but a result of a few, as described in [RFC 7672, 2.2.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7672#section-2.2.3). But the socketmap service could return `dane-only` if TLSA records for the MX servers are present, which should fix the problem.

Comment: @anx: That's why the policy resolver should respond with `dane-only` (instead of `dane`); "Mandatory DANE TLS. This is just like `dane` above, but DANE TLSA authentication is required. There is no fallback to `may` or `encrypt` when TLSA records are missing or unusable."

Comment: @EsaJokinen Indeed. I was wrong; [`dane-only` *does* ensure](https://github.com/vdukhovni/postfix/blob/17f9ea2314a4503c07f1035cfd26771f3fcd0a58/postfix/src/smtp/smtp_tls_policy.c#L789) its documented behaviour to defer instead, even in the "found but none usable" case.

Comment: I added [a comment](https://github.com/Snawoot/postfix-mta-sts-resolver/issues/67#issuecomment-1359686072) to a related issue on GitHub / Snawoot / [postfix-mta-sts-resolver](https://github.com/Snawoot/postfix-mta-sts-resolver/).